# Why was this flag for not an answer declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17237732/616443) as "not an answer", however it was declined with the reason "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". The entire answer is "Do you have tryed to put a png image in the wrapper?". Another user posted the comment that "This is not an answer." which got a couple of upvotes. Why was it declined? It hardly seems like anything other than a question or a comment from a user with not enough rep to do so.

Comment: The answer is very low quality. But it still contains a hint how to solve the issue. It is an attempt to answer the question - in a poor way

Comment: Well it is an answer. It's a terrible one, but it is a vague attempt at an answer. It deserves downvotes but it isn't something that a moderator actually needs to intervene to deal with - the downvotes will take care of that. If it was actually not an answer it'd be something like "I have this problem too, how do you solve it" or something like that.

Comment: It is somewhat answerish - it suggests a solution to the problem.

Comment: It is borderline, but it probably can be seen as a very poor attempt at answering the question. Moderators are instructed to fall on the side of it being an answer in these cases.

Comment: In the overwhelming majority of cases of similar answers in the past I've seen these "answers" converted into comments because the person answering usually doesn't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: Haha, "Do you have tryed to"

Comment: @Doorknob We all laughed at that one, yet no one edited it... <sigh>

Answer (score 2):

It was a suggestion, phrased in the form of a question rather than in the form of a command.  It's still an attempt to answer the question, it was just phrased grammatically as a rhetorical question.

In such cases the answer doesn't need to be deleted.  It should simply be edited so that it's grammatically in the form of a statement and not a question.  I [have done this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17237732/2) for this particular post.

In the case of this post it is also of low quality as the suggestion is not explained, it does not go into depth, and based on what I can see of others' reactions, didn't actually help solve the problem.  These are all reasons to downvote the post, but not to delete it or flag for moderator attention.

Comment: I understand that moderators cannot possibly be called upon to judge the technical merit of every question you're not honestly suggesting that _"Do you have tryed to put a png image in the wrapper?"_ is a valid answer are you? I would downvote, yes, but not having reached 20k yet I would also flag without hesitation.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm saying that it's not "not an answer".  It's not a *quality* answer, and without understanding the technical merits of the question, it doesn't appear to be a correct answer.  Neither of those make it "not an answer".  As such, it should just be downvoted.  Had it turned out to be correct and putting an image in the wrapper solved the OP's problem then what would your response be?  Clearly that's a proposed solution.  That it doesn't work doesn't change the fact that it's a (wrong) solution.